# What reputation awards what privileges?

Tags: support, reputation

I know that gaining reputation unlocks various privileges on the site. Things like being able to edit other people's posts or vote to close and reopen questions.

Where can I see the entire list of these privileges and the reputation required to unlock them?

Answer (score 1):

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges shows your current reputation, what privileges that gets you, and where you stand on getting others (e.g. 83% of the way to being able to create tags).

You can also find this page by hovering over your name in the top bar on the [main site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) and clicking "privileges", or by visiting the [Reputation section of the FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).